# ADTF no mediadescription for struct type " error

Tags: c++, adtf

**Explanation:**

My ADTF-Filter gets as input two double values and its output is a struct.
The struct contains a few double values.

```
typedef struct {
    double ValueX; 
    double ValueY; 
    double ValueZ; 
} tStruct;
```

**My problem:**

I wanted to see my values in "Signal View"
But I'm getting this error:

> warning | 00:00:15:015 | Media Description Service: No Media Description found for struct type '' on pin 'Filter/ValueX/'. This pin will not be available in SignalView! | media_description_signal_provider.cpp(158) | 12736/8516 | C:\tools\ADTF\2.14.2\bin\adtf_devenv.exe | OK | No error | cMediaManager_plugin

**What I have tried**

I played around a bit with the MediaDescription Editor and tried to see how it is done in the examples given by adtf. 
But nothing is working so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning (no error) describes exactly what is missing: There is no Media Description set on the output pin you are using your structure.

I guess you are using something like this in your Init method:

```
m_oOutputPin.Create("output", cObjectPtr<IMediaType>(new cMediaType(0, 0)), static_cast<IPinEventSink*> (this));
```

So you have to extend the media type creation with your struct:

```
m_oOutputPin.Create("output", cObjectPtr<IMediaType>(new cMediaType(0, 0, 0, "tStruct")), static_cast<IPinEventSink*> (this));
```

Then it will be set and also generated from your structure.

Have also a look at the demo https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf/v2/adtf_sdk_html_docs/page_demo_media_desc_coder.html and structure tSimpleStruct_BE for example